# How do load an HTML file in the template of a component in Angular?

Tags: angular

I am working on a site to demonstrate some of the side projects I've been working on. I've created a 'Project' component that has a title, list of technologies used and a url to a repository. I want to also be able to add a path to a basic html file that just has some text and headers that explains the project. I cannot figure out how to do this... do i need to create a separate component for each project?

The template currently looks something like this:

```
<a [href]="repositoryURL"><fa size="2x" name="github"></fa></a>
<h3 id="project-header">{{ title }}</h3>
<p>
  Technologies Used: {{ getTechnologiesList() }}
</p>
<div id="project-description">
  <!-- Here I want to include a description of the project with
     different paragraph and header elements, maybe some images  -->
</div>
```

---

**Edit:**

My solution was to store the HTML files in the src/assets folder, and access them using Http get request. I then stored the HTML as a string and set the `[innerHTML]` of the div element as the answer suggests.

This is what the Http request looks like:

```
descriptionPath : string = "multiquadris.htm";
projectDescription : string = "";

constructor(private http: HttpClient)
{
    this.http
        .get('assets/project-descriptions' + this.descriptionPath,
             { responseType: 'text' })
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.projectDescription = data;
        }
    );
}
```

And the template file:

```
<a [href]="repositoryURL"><fa size="2x" name="github"></fa></a>
<h3 id="project-header">{{ title }}</h3>
<p>
  Technologies Used: {{ getTechnologiesList() }}
</p>
<div [innerHTML]="projectDescription"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking out for is  **`[innerHtml]`**.You would need with something like this

```
<a [href]="repositoryURL"><fa size="2x" name="github"></fa></a>
<h3 id="project-header">{{ title }}</h3>
<p>
  Technologies Used: {{ getTechnologiesList() }}
</p>
<div id="project-description">
 <div [innerHtml]="yourHTML">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to store a path to a file as the `yourHTML` variable or does the html content have to be stored as a string?

Comment: you could use http get request to get the file and yes it should be string

Comment: @Sajeetharan what if you have angular related parts in html like (click)="clickHandler()" etc.

Comment: in that case you need https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 1):

In your component, did you set the template ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  templateUrl: './yourtemplate.html',
  styleUrls: ['./yourstyle.css']
})
```